# JQuery exclude thead when reading rows in <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table or rows, and each row has a `data-id` value.
The table is sortable. 
I need to get a list of the data-id values in the right order the table is in, and return them to my controller to re-assign the priority of items.

So I have tried to create a function that iterates through each row and builds a comma separated string.

```
 function GetOrder()
    {
        var ordered;
        $("#debt_list tr").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            if(id != 'NaN')
                ordered = ordered + id + ',';
        });
        var result = ordered.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
        return result;
    }
```

The issue I face is firstly, my first item, when I 'Alert' the result, is "NaN". So, my result looks like:

> "NaN,12,7,2,1"

I think this is because it's reading the 'Header' row, which has no data-id. Probably because of the `$("#debt_list tr")` line.

Can I stop it from reading the header? Or maybe I need to assign a class to each row? Poor fix might be to add a data-id=0 to the header and ignore that?

And I'm quite new to jquery - is this OK code for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do the following to exclude the header and access only tbody's rows is by $("#debt_list tbody tr")
and there is another mistake in your code you have not defined anything to variable ordered and trying to access it ,because of this it is returning NAN

```js
 function GetOrder()
    {
        var ordered="";
        $("#debt_list tbody tr").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
         
            if(id != 'NaN')
                ordered = ordered + id + ',';
        });
   
        var result = ordered.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
       
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @craig...let us know if it worked and what made it work

Comment: This was perfect, and educational. It seems the $(....) can filter down to the components you really care about, by adding classes. It seems to be the same as saying "Where the class is a debt_list, and is a tbody and is a tr". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the header row, change your selector like so: `#debt_list tr:not(:first-child)`

NaN is not a string, change your test from `if(id != 'NaN')` to `if (!isNaN(id))`